# How to complete $i^*i_*\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}$ into an exact triangle for a smooth divisor $i: X\hookrightarrow Y$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories, adjoint-functors, derived-functors

Let $Y$ be a smooth algebraic variety and $i: X\hookrightarrow Y$ be a smooth divisor. We consider the derived functors $i^*: D^b_{coh}(Y)\to D^b_{coh}(X)$ and $i_*:  D^b_{coh}(X)\to D^b_{coh}(Y)$. By adjunction, for any $\mathcal{F}\in D^b_{coh}(X)$ we have a canonical morphism $i^*i_*\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}$ in $D^b_{coh}(X)$.

My question is: Can we complete $i^*i_*\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}$ to an exact triangle in $D^b_{coh}(X)$? I am particularly interest in the case that $Y$ is Calabi-Yau and I guess that in this case the expected exact triangle should be
$$
i^*i_*\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}\otimes\omega_X^{-1}
$$
but I cannot prove or disprove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cone of $i^*i_*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(-X)[2]$.

EDIT. Let me write an argument for a sheaf $F$. Consider the distinguished triangle
$$
i^*i_*F \to F \to F'.
$$
We need to identify $F'$.
Applying $i_*$ we obtain
$$
i_*i^*i_*F \to i_*F \to i_*F'.\tag{*}
$$
By projection formula and the Koszul resolution of $i_*\mathcal{O}_X$, we have
$$
i_*i^*i_*F \cong 
i_*F \otimes i_*\mathcal{O}_X \cong
\mathrm{Cone}(i_*F \otimes \mathcal{O}_Y(-X) \to i_*F),
$$
and since the map in the right-hand side is obviously zero, we conclude that
$$
i_*i^*i_*F \cong 
i_*F \oplus i_*F \otimes \mathcal{O}_Y(-X)[1].
$$
Now the first map in $(*)$ is the projection to the direct summand, hence
$$
i_*F' \cong 
i_*F \otimes \mathcal{O}_Y(-X)[2] \cong
i_*(F \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(-X)[2]).
$$
Since $i_*$ is fully faithful on the category of sheaves, it follows from this that
$$
F' \cong F \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(-X)[2].
$$

Comment: Is it well-known? How to see it?

Comment: I think you can find this in the book of Huybrechts (FM transforms ...).

Comment: I think his Corollary 3.40 and Example 3.41 are closed to the result I want but they are still on different topic. Actually they compute $i^!$ but I am not sure if it implies the result you mentioned.

Comment: I am sure you can use for $i^*$ the same argument that is used for $i^!$. Alternatively, you can use the fact that $i^!$ differs from $i^*$ by a line bundle twist and shift, and applying this to the triangle for $i^!i_*$, obtain the triangle for $i^*i_*$.

Comment: Or you can just use the triangle for the unit $id \to i_*i^*$ and the "zig-zag" identities for the adjunction $(i^*, i_*)$ to get the one for the counit.

Comment: @Sasha Where can I find the triangle for $i^!i_*$?

Comment: @ZhaotingWei: What were you saying about Cor. 3.40  and Ex. 3.41 then?

Comment: @Sasha From Example 3.41 we can get $i^!=\mathcal{O}_X(X)[-1]\otimes i^*$ hence to prove $i^*i_*\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{O}_X(-X)[2]\otimes \mathcal{F}$ is exact is equivalent to prove $\mathcal{F}\to i^!i_*\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{O}_X(X)[-1]\otimes \mathcal{F}$ is exact. But I don't know how to prove either of them.

Comment: @ZhaotingWei: I added an argument to the answer.

Comment: The ongoing book of Huybrechts would also be helpful. You can find a link on his website.